# SF Process Builder Retiring RE MCC; what is the impact to activities in the SFMC (i.e., active journeys, automations, synchronized data extensions)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, process-builder, automationstudio, marketing-cloud-connect

Do any activities need to be stopped and restarted or will the MCC automate these processes? Are there any delays to be expected?